# MappingException - The class 'generalBundle\Entity\xxx' was not found in the chain configured namespaces xxx - Upgrade to symfony flex

Tags: php, symfony, orm, mapping, symfony-flex

I have a project in Symfony 3.4 and I am configuring flex, to later go to version 4.4.
I have already managed to modify the project folder structure, and it is trying to map, but the problem is that with the old configuration it does not work.

These are my bundles (I have kept the same structure here):

```
> SRC
     > H360 (the place of my bundles)
           > comercialBundle
           > jasperBundle
           > generalBundle
           > ...
```

And this is my orm config (i tried setting 'generalbundle'):

```
 orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
          generalBundle:
            type: annotation
            prefix: 'H360\generalBundle'
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/H360/generalBundle/Entity'
            is_bundle: false
          translatable:
            type: annotation
            alias: Gedmo
            prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
            # make sure vendor library location is correct
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
            is_bundle: false
```

And the error is: "The class 'generalBundle\Entity\GenParametros' was not found in the chain configured namespaces H360\generalBundle, Gedmo\Translatable\Entity"

Any ideas?

Comment: Your Prefix is H360\generalBundle but you seem to use generalBundle\Entity\GenParametros to import the entity. Change it to H360\generalBundle\Entity\GenParametros or change the prefix to generalBundle.

Comment: Now it works ! I almost got it hehe, thanksss @Vyctorya

Answer (score 1):

Your Prefix is H360\generalBundle but you seem to use generalBundle\Entity\GenParametros to import the entity. Change it to H360\generalBundle\Entity\GenParametros or change the prefix to generalBundle.